# remove category filter on catalog search

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, catalogsearch

If I add product to a category the catalog search works perfectly. But I dont want to use category filter on this. Actually I dont use category in my project.

Edit: I want to show category-less products on catalogsearch result page. That's why I want to remove category filter.

So, how can I remove category filter on catalog search? I think It's about core code but I dont know which file I need to edit.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following node to `local.xml` file of your theme:

```
<catalogsearch_result_index>
    <reference name="catalogsearch.leftnav">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>category_filter</name></action>
    </reference>
</catalogsearch_result_index>
```

Comment: I want to show category-less products on catalogsearch result page. That's why I want to remove category filter.

Comment: Isn't it what my answer addresses?

Comment: It doesnt work, For test only one product has category, the other ones not. Now, search returning one product only.

Comment: I think there is a has-category-filter or something on core code.

Comment: What is the "Visibility" setting of your product?

Comment: Catalog and Search

Comment: how to do the same in magento2

Comment: @sangan please ask a separate question.

Comment: yes i already asked question ..  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/204543/how-can-i-disable-filter-category-from-filters-in-search-result-page-magento2?noredirect=1#comment284039_204543

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using the default magento layout-

Open `app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/catalogsearch.xml`

```
<catalogsearch_result_index translate="label">
    <reference name="root" >
        <action method="setTemplate" >< template >page/1column.phtml< /template ></action>
    </reference>
</catalogsearch_result_index>
```

Since you are not using Layer left block this will solve your issue.

Comment: I think I cant tell the problem correctly. The problem is I want to show category-less products on catalog search result page. Because I dont use category on magento.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it via XML you should edit catalog.xml

replace:

```
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" 
    after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml" />
```

with this:

```
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">  
    <action method="unsetChild"><alias>category_filter</alias></action>
</block>
```

Comment: I think I cant tell the problem correctly. The problem is I want to show category-less products on catalog search result page. Because I dont use category on magento.

Comment: This is not on the catalog search page...it is on catalog listing page

Answer (score 1):

You may be better off creating a category to hold the products, include in Menu set to false.  You can also set the category to not available and use `getChildrenCategoriesWithInactive`,  and assign all your "search" based non category products to search over only this category.

You'll want to look over the Layer Filter Category, possibly overriding `getCategory()` or `apply()` within: `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Category.php`

For example:

```
    /**
     * Get selected category object
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Category
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        $rootCat = 4; // <- your new category ID
        $this->_categoryId = $rootCat;
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($rootCat);

        Mage::register('current_category_filter', $category, true);

        return $category;
    }
```

- [http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.8/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Category.php](http://goo.gl/Xk25CL)

Related Stackoverflow question:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862967/magento-get-selected-filter-in-layered-navigation

Also, if you do go this route, don't edit the core file but make a module version or at the very least an `app/code/local/Mage/` copy.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add all products to the root category. As if there is no category set then this category is added as a filter to search results.

This would save you save you from having to change core code and I think it would give you the results you are looking for.

The root category can be returned via `Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId()`

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php $catalogSearchHelper =  $this->helper('catalogsearch'); ?>
<form id="search_mini_form" action="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getResultUrl() ?>" method="get">
    <div class="form-search">
        <label for="search"><?php echo $this->__('Search:') ?></label>
        <input id="search" type="text" name="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getQueryParamName() ?>" value="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getEscapedQueryText() ?>" class="input-text" maxlength="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getMaxQueryLength();?>" />
        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Search')) ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Search') ?></span></span></button>
        <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form', 'search', '<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->jsQuoteEscape($this->__('Search entire store here...')) ?>');
            searchForm.initAutocomplete('<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getSuggestUrl() ?>', 'search_autocomplete');
        //]]>
        </script>
    </div>
</form>
```